# How to update a record of certain column of one row by selecting via radiobutton and pressing a button

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, radio-button, sql-update

I want to update a column of a selected row in gridview after selecting radiobutton. Forexample, I have Candidiate table with ID, Name, Address, Email, Phone, Status etc. 
Once I select radiobutton, it ties to ID. Then, based on ID, I want to change the record where Status column is assigned either "Y" or "N". I have achieved tying down radiobutton with ID. After that, I am lost to identifying ID with correct record row.
Please help me advise with sample codes.

Thank in advance.
Joe
Below is my html code.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvCandidates" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    BackColor="Green" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor = "#C2D69B"
    BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" AllowPaging = "true">
    <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select One">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <input name="SelectedRadioButton" type="radio" 
                value='<%# Eval("CANDIDATE_ID") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CANDIDATE_ID" HeaderText="CANDIDATE_ID" 
            SortExpression="CANDIDATE_ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CANDIDATE_NAME" HeaderText="CANDIDATE_NAME" 
            SortExpression="CANDIDATE_NAME" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CANDIDATE_ADDRESS1" HeaderText="CANDIDATE_ADDRESS1" 
            SortExpression="CANDIDATE_ADDRESS1" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CANDIDATE_PHNO" HeaderText="CANDIDATE_PHNO" 
            SortExpression="CANDIDATE_PHNO" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CANDIDATE_EMAIL_ADDRESS" 
            HeaderText="CANDIDATE_EMAIL_ADDRESS" SortExpression="CANDIDATE_EMAIL_ADDRESS" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CANDIDATE_STATUS" HeaderText="CANDIDATE_STATUS" 
            SortExpression="CANDIDATE_STATUS" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Below is my c# code.

```
protected void btnAccepted_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string CStatus = "Y";
  string selectedValueID = Request.Form["SelectedRadioButton"];
  lblMsgStatus.Visible = true;
  lblMsgStatus.Text = selectedValueID;


    compCon = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
    compCon.Open();
    string UpdateQuery = @"UPDATE CandidateDetails SET CANDIDATE_STATUS='Y' WHERE CANDIDATE_ID='@selectedValueID'";
    SqlCommand UpdateCandidateCommand = new SqlCommand(UpdateQuery, compCon);
    UpdateCandidateCommand.Connection = compCon;

    UpdateCandidateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    compCon.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to update on selection of radio button for single record or update for all records on button Accepted click?

Comment: I want to update a single record by clicking Accepted Button after selecting a single record via radio button.

Comment: You can loop through gridview & with datakey you can get for which record radio button selection is made & then save data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below, you can get id as shown in Test button click:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gv" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="10" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound" 
DataKeyNames="TestId">
        <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Test" DataField="TestId" />
         <asp:TemplateField>
          <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn1" runat="server" Text="Yes" />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn2" runat="server" Text="No" />
          </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Test" OnClick="btnTest_Click" />


protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in gv.Rows)
 {
   string theDataKey = gv.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();//Id field
   RadioButton rbtn1 = gvrow.FindControl("rbtn1") as RadioButton;
   RadioButton rbtn2 = gvrow.FindControl("rbtn2") as RadioButton;
   string YesNo = "N";//set default value
   if(rbtn1.Checked)
   YesNo = "Y";
   else if(rbtn2.Checked)
   YesNo = "N";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank. Let me try with your code. Thank you in millions.

Comment: The code is not working. In debugging, at string theDataKey, the index is out of range. Seem like index of selected row is not read. Please advise. Thank.

Comment: Add your Id field as data key for Gridview :DataKeyNames="TestId"

Comment: Still not working. At "if" statement if (rbtn.checked), the error shows object is not created properly. I think that object was not created properly in radiobutton and I dont know how to create.

Comment: What Id you gave to Radio buttons for Yes/No?

Comment: Id for radio buttons is SelectedRB. Thank for helping me.I dont have two radiobuttons because I am using gridviews. I used only this <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn1" runat="server" />

Comment: RadioButton rbtn1 = gvrow.FindControl("rbtn1") as RadioButton;
  If id for radio button is different then make sure to change it in find control method.

Comment: Thank in millions. Let me try again. Hope this time I go through.

Answer (score 0):

you should to use:

```
string UpdateQuery = @"UPDATE CandidateDetails SET CANDIDATE_STATUS='Y' WHERE CANDIDATE_ID IN ( [SELECTED VALUES]);
```

and in order [SELECTED VALUES] you should to place comma seperated values 
for example (1,2,4,7,9) or ('a','f','amita','david')

Comment: Hi Farrokh, I still don't get what you are trying to say. Do you want me to replace SELECTED VALUES with variable name SelectedValueID. If so, it is still not working. Any idea, please.... thank so much for your help. I am just a begineer for asp .net.

Comment: I think you want to update multiple record together,so yo should to get his records key field(for example id) and seperate them with comma, then put them inside the ().understand ?